# FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() - Unable to connect to the remote server - only sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to upload a file to a 3rd party FTP server. It is successful most of the time, but sometimes there is a time period that could last a few minutes where it fails. The exception is raised when I call `GetRequestStream()` and the message is `Unable to connect to the remote server` with no inner exception or additional information. The timeout for my request is set to 100000 but the exception is raised sometime around 20 seconds.

I have also logged the IP address of the FTP server at the time of the request, and I have seen the same IP address sometimes work and sometimes fail to connect, so I do not think it would be a firewall issue.

This `Upload` method is used as part of an API call using ASP.NET Web API, where the user makes this API call to trigger the upload.

Code:

```
try
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(hostURI);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPPW"]);
    request.EnableSsl = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    byte[] fileContents;
    using (var readStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
    {
        fileContents = new byte[readStream.Length];
        readStream.Read(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        readStream.Close();
    }

    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Message: " + e.Message + ", Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace + ", Inner Exception: " + e.InnerException);
}
```

Exception:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server at 
>       System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at 
>       PGServer.Helpers.FTPHelper.Upload(String pathToFile, String ftpFolderName, String newFileName)

Comment: At the time you are not able to transfer a file with your code, are you able to transfer a file using a standalone FTP client between the same two machines?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It is hard to catch the time frame when the upload does not work in code, but I did try connecting & uploading with filezilla immediately after a request failed in code, and I had no problems. But, I tried sending from the code again after the filezilla success, and it worked, so it's hard to say if that was a good test or not.

Comment: Without that information, it's difficult to asses what the problem is.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I just tried sending 2 requests one right after the other (by calling my API method twice less than 1 second apart) and one succeed and one failed. Not sure if that helps at all. Other times they both succeed when calling right after the other.

Comment: Did you try to script a frequent connect/upload/disconnect using some scriptable FTP client (e.g. WinSCP)? To check if you get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

the same error.the ftp works safely more the one year. recently it show "**Unable to connect to the remote server 
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()**"
here what I did：
 0 uninstall the Anti-virus software。
1 reboot the computer which the ftp in。it works